# Private server with domain name structure

Tags: centos, ip, private-network

I'm doing some tests/studying on a private server but I don't understand the structure.

It's a centos server. This server has a private IP 10.x.x.x. This server is also linked to a domain name, so it has to have a public IP too I think. But if I print the server address with PHP, it print only 10.x.x.x. What happens here? There's an IP redirect(is this possible?) in the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your public IP on the server with the following commands:

```
wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo
```

or

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

To know all tyhe interfaces on the server you can use:

```
ip addr
```

From a service like //http://viewdns.info/ or http://www.fifi.org/services/traceroute you can check the IP corresponding to a domain name and verify if it's the same as the public IP on step 1.

A server in a private network can be in public internet opening a port in the router that connects that server to internet. So, if you want to use that server as web server you just open port 80 and redirects everything coming to port 80 to the private IP of the server.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. If there're more servers like mine, everyone with a different IP but the same router, how's the traffic redirected to the specific server? You can open a port and do a selective redirect basing on IP?

Comment: If there are more physical servers sharing the same router, the router will have to send everything coming to port 80 to a redirecting server. It inspects the HTTP header of the incoming packet, extracts the name and with that information can do the redirection to the appropiate server.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about this solution? I'd good for a public domain name, consisting Google for example?

Comment: Depends of the expected incoming traffic. Google needs to use very sophisticated systems to ensure quick response and high availability. I know that a simple server using `apache`can do the task of redirecting server, but in a high traffic situation it can be a bottle neck. Read about `virtual hosting`to learn how hosting providers do this.

Comment: I've executed `wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo` and it gave me a different result from viewdns. How can this be possible?

Comment: Then, the domain name is not associated with your actual public IP and it is going to any other place, From the centOS server do a `traceroute` to the IP result of ViewDNS. It could give you a clue.

Comment: It gave me 30 "* * *". If I visit example.com/test.html, I see the "test.html" file I'm working on this server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21284/discussion-between-jcbermu-and-testermaster).

Comment: Solved in chat. The Internet router has two public IPs, one used for outgoing and another for incoming.

Comment: I'm studying the situation about virtual hosts and I think that there's something still missing: http://www.tecmint.com/apache-ip-based-and-name-based-virtual-hosting/ I think that you're speaking about an IP Based virtual hosting, right? But I've access to all the configuration of the server, and other websites with similar IP x.x.x.Y (Y is the only different part) are in another server I think, as in this server I've access to all config httpd included.